# Type safe data binding to ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, type-safety

I have a `myList = List<MyClass>`. I bind this list to a `ComboBox`:

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myList;
```

Trouble is, it's not type safe. I can't do:

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem.Some_member_method();
```

Instead I have to do:

```
((MyClass) myComboBox.SelectedItem).Some_member_method();
```

I don't want to cast every single time. How can I tell this `ComboBox` that its members will always be of type `MyClass`?

Comment: Why is it not type safe? and what's bad with casting? well casting is bad when you can't be sure if your object is a instance of a specific class. then you could use the `as`operator: `myComboBox.SelectedItem as MyClass` so you can check this for null if `SelectedItem` is not an instance of `MyClass`

Comment: I can understand that you feel a little bit uncomfortable when you cast an object to something, because you could get an cast exception when you aren't allowed to cast it to your class. but there is no other way. the return type of SelectedItem must be `Object` because `Object` is "everything". So if you want maximum flexibility this is the only return type you can have for `SelectedItem`. So the only way is casting `SelectedItem` to the Class you put in before. Teach me if i am wrong.

Comment: @JensHorstmann Since the question isn't "should I avoid typecasting", I'll refrain from that discussion. I feel it is clear what I am asking; if not please do let me know.